# replace android native app to React native app on store

Tags: android, react-native

Can someone please advise we are in a situation here..

Our app is already on play store built in using android native but now we have created new app using react native and we would like to replace our same app on store by react native without affective existing users?

1. Does android allow to replace same native app by react app I mean can we just simple push as new version on store for same?
2. If allow will that impact our existing user I mean when they will upgrade the app, would it be a simple upgrade?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we did such thing recently in our team your answers would be as below:

1. Yes, its allowed to replace an old native app with a new react app, because the play store or any other app stores receive an `APK` file from you, so there won't be any problems.
2. Make sure that your new react app has the same **package name** as your old app, and that it's signed with the same **signing key** (`keystore` or `.jks` file) as the old one was.

And you're good to go!

Comment: yes, same **package name** and same **signing key** must be enough

Comment: Can we get databases and internal files as backup? or what?

Comment: @Al-Amin Yes, you can retrieve databases and files stored on the device by the previous version of the application.